# Implementing LuaCocoa on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, lua

It is stated in http://playcontrol.net/opensource/LuaCocoa/other-luaobjective-c-bridge.html that LuaCocoa supports Mac implementation. Thus, the available framework, luacocoa.framework is compiled for Mac platform.

However, I wanted to try to compile it on iOS platform to see if it works. So, I downloaded LuaCocoa source code and tried to compile it on iOS platform. Obviously, there are errors. I have this:

```
 "target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework', but there's no such  
  product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform"
```

I believe that is due to iOS unable to run dynamic library.

So my question is: anyone successfully compile luacocoa on iOS platform and is there any chance luacocoa able to be used on iOS platform.

If there are better suggestion to bridge ObjC-Lua, do let me know as well.

Comment: I'm not that big in iOS, but the error message simply states that you can't compile it as a framework which is no big surprise; Sandboxing of Apps in iOS would make something like an OSX framework quite useless. So you would have to change the project to a library product type. Not sure how easy that is though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Wax](https://github.com/probablycorey/wax)

It is an Lua - Obj-C bridge for iOS that has been around for a long time.

[Here is a nice article about it](http://mobileorchard.com/announcing-iphone-wax-native-uikit-iphone-apps-written-in-lua/).

Comment: Checked my answer. I have explained y i did not use Wax.

Comment: I see. API differences. You would need to add another layer that did API translation to use Wax. Not really that elegant.